# Why ProactorEventLoop on Windows not working with serial port?

Tags: python-3.x

Have tried IOCP on Windows (which ProactorEventLoop is based on) with serial port. It worked with my Visual C++ test program.

Just wonder why ProactorEventLoop only supports sockets, but not file descriptors like serial port. This is the case with Python 3.5.1 as far as I understand.

Comment: Is it possible to use IOCP with the low-level POSIX API?  I imagine not.  But that's what `os.open()` and friends are built on.

Answer (score 2):

Because Python's asyncio is a slightly disgusting pile of ad-hoc hacks, and not much thought went into the consistency of the design.

You can actually feed serial port file handles into ProactorEventLoop, but you need to use private and undocumented functions. See https://github.com/m-labs/asyncserial which does exactly that.